# How to prevent parent frame closed when closing child frame (Java + iReport)?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, awt, frame

Basically I want to call ***`JasperViewer`*** from a button on my Main Application.
I use this

```java
private void btnExportActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            JasperPrint printer = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("reportRecharge.jasper"), params, new JREmptyDataSource());
            JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(printer);
            jv.setVisible(true);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

When a ***`JasperViewer`*** appear and I close it, the `main frame` / `parent` also closed. I've try adding `jv.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);` but it's not working either. How to get it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try parent.invalidate() after closing the JasperViewer.

Comment: where do I put the code? I'm not understand "after closing the JasperViewer"

Comment: in onclose method of JasperViewer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**change like below. if you add false the default exit on close property becomes false.**

```
private void btnExportActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            JasperPrint printer = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("reportRecharge.jasper"), params, new JREmptyDataSource());
            JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(printer,false);
            jv.setVisible(true);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: I've just read this reply, Big thanks Mr @Siddhu , now it works!